# Java/Android - Writing to Outputstream after reading from Inputstream

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, inputstream, outputstream

On my PC i start a Server to send Bytes over Bluetooth to an Android Phone.
I am sending Every 10 seconds different Bytes using the same Outputstream.

```
outputStream.write(buffer);
outputStream.flush();
thisThread.sleep(10000);
```

buffer being a bytearray which changes every loop

Now i want to read the buffer on the Android Phone:

```
while((bytes = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  //do something
}
//do more
```

My problem is now that read(buffer) doesnt return -1.
How can i notify the Android Phone that the bytes have been transfered so i can do
the things i want after the while loop?

Comment: I prefer  object streams  it solves problems like this

Comment: never tried with objectstream, never heard of it before. so i have to transform my bytearray to an object and call ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(object) ?

Comment: ObjectStreams  are   one of the best thinks about java. Your class has to implement  the serializable interface ( its just a formality there are no functions) then you create a ObjectOutputStream :new ObjectOutputStream(someOtherStream) thats it  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/objectoutputstream.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried closing connection on PC side? From your example it looks like you have not.

[edit] if you do not want to close connection on PC side, then send known byte sequence which will indicate to andorid app that PC side finished sending data and ie. is waiting for response

Comment: Tried to close but doesnt worked either. Also i dont want to close it. Finally i made it with the known sequence like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
while((bytes = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
//
}
```